# What is use of the annotation @JsonIgnore?

Tags: java, json, hibernate, spring-boot

I'm joining tables with one to many cardinality, the classes I'm using refer to each other. And I'm using @JsonIgnore annotation with out understanding it deeply.

Comment: Ignoring properties?

Comment: @chrylis sorry  I didn't understand what do you mean?

Comment: Please refer to [Annotation Type JsonIgnore](https://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-annotations/javadoc/2.5/com/fasterxml/jackson/annotation/JsonIgnore.html).

Answer (score 16):

`@JsonIgnore` is used to ignore the logical property used in **serialization** and **deserialization**. `@JsonIgnore` can be used at **setters**, **getters** or **fields**.

If you add `@JsonIgnore` to a field or its getter method, the field is not going to be serialized.

Sample POJO:

```
class User {
    @JsonIgnore
    private int id;
    private String name;
    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }
    @JsonIgnore
    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }
    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }
    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }  
}
```

Sample code for serialization:

```
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
User user = new User();
user.setId(2);
user.setName("Bob");
System.out.println(mapper.writeValueAsString(user));
```

Console output:

> {"name":"Bob"}

Comment: If i put @JsonIgnore property on a fetch type lazy collection, does this implies that lazy data will not be loaded?

Answer (score 3):

When serializing your object into Json, the fields that are tagged with @JsonIgnore will not be included in the serialized Json object. This attribute is read by the Json serialize using reflection.

Answer (score 1):

The Jackson's [`@JsonIgnore`](https://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-annotations/javadoc/2.9/com/fasterxml/jackson/annotation/JsonIgnore.html) annotation can be placed on fields, getters/settess and constructor parameters mark a property to be **ignored** during the serialization to JSON (or deserialization from JSON). Refer to the [Jackson annotations reference documentation](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-annotations/wiki/Jackson-Annotations) for more details.